# How to create sub groups in ion auth codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I know we can create groups in ion auth. But I need sub group inside members and staff groups.The following user roles are required for my project.

1. Admin
2. Members

   - plan A members
   - plan B members
   - plan C members
3. Staff

   - technical staff
   - management staff
   - general staff

Based on plan selected by member, the 'views' and functionalities will change.

I was thinking of adding a new column to users table to specify the plan used.
Another option is to create 3 plan groups without parent member group. 
Is there any other way to add sub groups using ion auth?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far? I mean thinking is fine, but please provide code and tell what works / not with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Arunu - your idea to make them each groups, not subgroups, is the best way to go.

There is no real reason to have a hierarchy of permissions (I think you may be mixing authentication with ACL a bit, a very easy thing to do).

Ion_auth is set up so that a user can have multiple groups - so, for example, all your users could have a Members record, and then a separate record for each sub group.

Each controller entry point simply says what groups are allowed in or not - it treats them all the same.

also, you can dynamically display data based on what groups the user belongs to