# Codeigniter 3 Ion_auth sub-groups

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ion-auth

I need to find a solution with Ion_auth and Codeigniter 3 and need help. We need to have sub-groups in main-groups but not repeat every sub-groups. A user should be able to have two main-groups and one sub-groups or several sub-groups.

- SuperAdmin
- SuperEconomy

  - Cost divisions 1

    - Admin
    - Economy
    - Sales
    - Cashier
    - General staff
  - Cost divisions 2

    - Admin
    - Economy
    - Sales
    - Cashier
    - General staff
  - Cost divisions 3

    - Admin
    - Economy
    - Sales
    - Cashier
    - General staff

For more explanation we have multiple cost divisions and different user types in cost divisions like, admin, sales, cashier, economy etc etc. But sales in one sub-group should not see sales in an other sub-groups if they are not in both head group.

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Comment: [This answer says you don't need sub groups.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14956095/3585500) Just create as many groups as you need and assign the users to any groups they need.

Comment: Yes, I also found that solutions but it doesn't work for us because we need to have some kind of limitation of main-groups because a user should be able to select between two or three cost divisions or main-groups.